# Erro de importação de dados no R

Tags: r, csv

Olá!
Eu importei uma base que eu pedi via LAI para o R. Me enviaram em excel, mas converti em csv por facilidades de trabalho.
Eu sei que ao transformar todas os dados das colunas de "caractere" para "numeric", uma delas fica com os valores multiplicados por 1000. Se transformo para "integer",esse problema não acontece e tô pensando em trabalhar com a base assim. 
Isso não ocorre quando importo os mesmos dados em excel, todas as colunas permanecem com os mesmos valores que estavam quando em caractere... O que pode ser?

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com 1) as instruções que usou para importar o ficheiro CSV. 2)  a saída de `dput(dados)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(dados 20))`?

Comment: Isso acontece pq provavelmente o csv está separando decimais por "," e não por "." como é esperado pelo R. Você pode tentar usar a função `read.csv2` e ver se corrige o problema.